# Existence of solution of ordinary differential equation

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I am reading a proof of the existence of solutions for ordinary differential equations and I have some basic doubt. I'll copy the statement, the part of the proof I don't understand and my question:

**Statement**

Let $I$ be an interval of the real line. Let $f(t,x)$ be a Lipschitz function on the variable $x$ on $I \times \mathbb R$. Let $\tau \in I, \xi \in \mathbb R$. If $\tau \in I^{\circ}$, then there is $\lambda >0$ and a continuous differentiable function $x:[\tau-\lambda,\tau+\lambda] \subset I \to \mathbb R$ such that $$x'(t)=f(t,x(t)) \forall t \in [\tau-\lambda,\tau+\lambda]$$ $$x(\tau)=\xi$$

**Sketch of the proof**

It is easy to show that finding a solution to the system $$x'(t)=f(t,x(t)) \forall t \in [\tau-\lambda,\tau+\lambda]$$ $$x(\tau)=\xi$$

is equivalent to find a solution to the integral equation $$x(t)=\xi+\int_\tau^t f(s,x(s))ds$$

So we define inductively define $$x_0=\xi,$$ $$x_1=\xi+\int_\tau^t f(s,x_0(s))ds,$$ $$x_k(t)=\xi+\int_\tau^t f(s,x_{k-1}(s))ds$$

and if we show that this sequence of functions converges uniformly on the interval 
$[\tau-\lambda,\tau+\lambda]$ to a function $x(t)$, then we have that $x(t)$ is continuous and that $\int_\tau^t f(s,x_k(s))ds \to \int_\tau^t f(s,x(s))ds$. This means $x(t)$ is a solution of the integral equation and therefore a solution to the original system.

**Question**

Now, in my textbook it says that the functions $x_k(t)$ are defined on the interval $I$, it may be a silly little detail but I don't see why these functions are defined on that interval just from the fact $x_k(t)=\xi+\int_\tau^t f(s,x_{k-1}(s))ds$, I would appreciate if someone could explaine me how to check this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add the condition that $f(t,x)$ is continuous on $I\times\mathbb{R}$.

$x_0(t)$ is constantt, so it is defined on $I$. The function $f(s,x_0(s))$ is defined and continuous on $I$, and hence, Riemann integrable on $I$. Then $x_1$ is defined and continuous on $I$. Induction shows that $x_k$ is defined on $I$ for all $k$.

Comment: I was wondering: are you sure you need continuity of $f$? In my textbook the hypothesis is that $f$ is Lipschitz on $x$ but not necessarily continuous. Using the Lipschitz condition, one can show that $f(s,x_0(s))=f(s,\xi)$ is continuous, the rest follows exactly as you've said.

Comment: If $f$ is discontinuous how do you define the solution?